# Generic fake query for empty result in Jpa criteria api

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

In legacy code I have the following:

```
public class NoFilter<T> implements FilterClause{
Class entityClass;
public NoFilter(Class aClass)
{
    entityClass = aClass;
}

@Override
public CriteriaQuery query4Data(EntityManager em ) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(rt);
    return cq;
}
}
```

Executing the query it returns all the entities unfiltered of the requested type.

I would need a fake query which always returns an empty list. Cannot write anything related to the specific entity in the **where** clause because it should be valid with all entity types. Don't know how to write it in JPA criteria Api.

Cannot use the **limit** keyword to restrict to 0 result.

The result I would like to achieve is the same I get with Mysql executing

> SELECT * FROM users where 0>1;

Comment: what about `cq.select(rt).where(cb.disjunction())` (sorry i did not test it, but empty disjunction() should return false)

Comment: `cb.greaterThan(cb.literal(0), cb.literal(1))`, or `cb.isFalse(cb.literal(Boolean.TRUE))`, or ...